# How can i redirect a url through my proxy site

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy

I am working on a "A proxy site" all the code is ready but i have a problem, when a user enters the url directly into my site it gets processed and loads from the proxysite but I if he clicks a hyperlink it from the website and not from mine, what i need is a way of how i can redirect the url through my site, is it possible ?

eg:

Foxyproxy when you enter www.google.com it loads the site through it, and when you search something it still loads the result page through foxyproxy, what i cant do is load the result page or any other sub-page through my site.

Thanks and Regards :)

Comment: If you are having this problem, your "proxy site" is also probably not working how you expect with respect to the resources on the page being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to read the entire response from third-party external site and replace all links, header Locations, and other external URLs with your proxy site URL appending the original URL as a URL parameter (or however you get the requested page from the HTTP request: GET param, URL routing, etc.). Then send the modified result to the client.

Comment: +1... Don't forget that some Urls are constructed via JavaScript, so may not be able to fix all of them.

Comment: Or is there a way of making a listener that checks if every click is coming from an iframe and if it is then gets the source and handles the rest from there ?